# How to check if the shift or control keys are pressed in a vs2022 extension

Tags: keyboard, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2022

I want to be able to check if the shift or control keys are pressed in a vs2022 extension, if possible, at any point.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Include:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;
```

And then the following in your code:

```
var keyboard = new Keyboard();

if( keyboard.ShiftKeyDown == true
    || keyboard.CtrlKeyDown == true )
{
    ....
}
```